# How would i extract certain patterns from an InputStream in java and then place into a byteArray

Tags: java, byte, arrays, inputstream

i am looking for a method in java, to extract certain bytes from an input stream.
for example
i will have this stream of data occuring

```
0x01,0x02,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x03,0x04,0x00,0x01,0x09,0x08,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01
```

my encoding scheme is type data ending
firstly i will check the first byte, 
then i will want to store all the data in a byte array from 0x01 untill the occurance of `0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01` except for the `0x01`'s

so the first piece of data i would place into the array

```
0x01,0x02,0x00,0x00
```

and then onto the next , 
this begins with a `0x03` and ends with `0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01`
i would like for this to be placed in another byte array as,

```
0x03,0x04,0x00,0x01,0x09,0x08,0x00,0x00
```

how would i go about doing this, i began with using

a ByteArrayOutputStream to add dynamically to the byte array, without needing to know the size,
but im lost on the logic on how would extract out each pattern and remove each 0x01 following a 0x00, 
also im rading a byte in from an input stream , one byte at a time (its the only way i can get the bytes)

Comment: Please add some structure and formatting to the question (e.g. code blocks, paragraphs instead of single lines). In it's current state, I'm not willing to look at it closer

Comment: no problem, did it for you, if u there anything else let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a finite-state recognizer.  For your simple syntax the following pseudocode should do the trick:

```
state = 0;
while( (byte=input.read()) != EOF)
{
    switch(state)
    {
        case 0:     // "normal" state
            if (byte == 0x00)
            {
                state = 1;
                buf.append(byte);
            }
            else
                output.write(byte)
            break;
        case 1:     // We've seen a 0x00
            if (byte == 0x00)
            {
                state = 1;
                output.write(buf);
            }
            else if (byte == 0x01)
            {
                state = 2;
                buf.append(byte);
            }
            else
            {
                output.write(buf);
                buf.clear();
                state = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 2:     // We've seen 0x00,0x01
            if (byte == 0x00)
            {
                state = 3;
                buf.append(byte);
            }
            else if (byte == 0x01)
            {
                output.write(0x00);
                buf.clear();
                state = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                output.write(buf);
                buf.clear();
                state = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 3:     // We've seen 0x00,0x01,0x00
            if (byte == 0x00)
            {
                state = 1;
                output.write(buf);
                buf.clear();
                buf.append(byte);
            }
            else if (byte == 0x01)
            {
                // The last four input bytes were 0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01
                state = 0;
                output.write(0x00,0x00);
                buf.clear
            }
            else
            {
                output.write(buf);
                buf.clear();
                state = 0;
            }
            break;
    }
}
if (!buf.empty()) output.write(buf);
```

This works by reading bytes one at a time.

If it detects a 0x00, we need to start looking for the delimiter pattern but save the bytes in case later we find it was a false alarm.  The "state" variable keeps track of what we've seen so far.  At each point if the input matches the next expected delimiter byte we save it, bump the state and keep going.  If at any point we don't get the next expected delimiter byte we just write out all the saved data, clear the buffer and go back to "normal" state.  However, if we eventually see the entire delimiter string, we write out 0x00,0x00 and discard the saved bytes (which would be 0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01).

EDIT: Code modified to handle additional condition from OP and comment from @Shaded

Comment: EOF = END OF FILE , i will be using a network connection, how would i determine there are no more bytes being sent? , thank u for your answer, i will see if i can somehow implement it and post the code, cheers

Comment: You'll have to adjust this pseudocode to your particular input and output mechanisms.  You may not have an end-of-file but "connection closed" instead.

Comment: Yeah, in absence of higher level abstractions, state machines are the way to go (or something to create them). It might simplify code to create symbolic constants for states.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, Little issue with your state machine, since this is a repeating pattern you're looking for you have to handle cases such as 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01 
Your machine would have a problem when it expects a 0x01 and get's another 0x00.

Comment: @Jim Garrison , in my format, when i receive a 0x00,0x01,0x01 , i would also have to strip away just to leave 0x00, how would i go about this with your pseudo code above, i have implemented it, yet this is just another conditional

Comment: @Shaded not sure what you mean - the first 0x00 would be written out when the second 0x00 was seen.

Comment: @molleman well, that wasn't in your original spec.  Once you understand how this works you should be able to modify it to handle different patterns, although if there is much more complexity then another approach might be better.  Update your post to include ALL the requirements.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, In the situation I described above the second 0x00 would need to put the machine into state 1, but yours would put it back to state 0.

Comment: @Shaded good point. The code gets unwieldy pretty quickly, which is why I usually make FSMs table-driven.  I thought for such a simple pattern an if-then-else FSM would be OK.  I'll fix the pseudocode.

Comment: @molleman: I updated the pseudocode to show how it could be accomplished in this framework; however, this is untested pseudocode so you should play around with it in Java to understand the finite-state-machine concepts.  Using a debugger to step through an unfamiliar algorithm is always useful.